# Don't remove trailing zero on ToString

Tags: c#, tostring

I have two doubles, 4.0 and 4.12345. I want to use ToString on them to receive just that, 4.0 and 4.12345, however the default ToString trims the 0 in 4.0 and if I try to use formats with F / N, I either have to pad or to round. Is there an easy generic solution I can use?

Thanks!

Comment: How do you distinguish the significant digits? A plain double structure can't distinguish between 4.0 and 4.000

Comment: `.ToString("n1")` doesn't work for you?

Comment: double `4.0` is equal to `4`, `4.00` , `4.000` etc... `ToString` doesn't know which one you want. you have to use formats. easiest way is to not use doubles and use string from scratch and only convert them to double whenever needed for example for calculation.

Comment: How about something like this: `.ToString(".0####")`? You can add as many hashes as you want digits.

Comment: @BryanWoodford You should add that as the answer.

Comment: @BryanWoodford Not much use if he also has a `4`...

Comment: @Rawling It works with `4` - the output from `4d.ToString(".0####")` is `"4.0"`, which is just what the OP wants.

Comment: @Rawling - for converting doubles, it will work.

Comment: @MatthewWatson Not if he wants to distinguish between a `4` and a `4.0`.

Comment: @Rawling I don't understand - there's no difference between 4 and 4.0 for a double? (i.e. `Trace.Assert(4d == 4.0d);`)

Comment: @MatthewWatson Yes, but OP seems to think he has a `4.0` rather than just a `4`, so he could also have a `4`, `4.00`, `4.000`...

Comment: @Rawling I don't think that's really what he thinks - I expect he just typed that because that's the output he wanted. But only the OP knows what they really meant - maybe he'll clarify it later...

Answer (score 2):

You can use the below format:

```
double number = 4.12345;
string s = number.ToString(".0####");
```

Which still maintains the '.0':

```
double number = 4.0;
string s = number.ToString(".0####");
```

You can add as many hashes as you want digits.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the format below to convert double to string.

```
{0:0.00000}
```

More zeros can be added according to your need.

```
double myNumber = 4.12345;
var s = string.Format("{0:0.00000}", myNumber);
Console.WriteLine(s);
```

Updated code using ToString

```
double myNumber = 4.12345;
string s = myNumber.ToString("0.00000");
Console.WriteLine(s);
```

Comment: That'll give  `4.00000`, not `4.0`, won't it?

Comment: @Rawling but OP wants 4.12345 at the same time, so this is the only choice.